# Modding Smalltalk image

Tags: smalltalk

I have a third party program that was written with "Visual Smalltalk 3.1.0 Enterprise", as it is written in the ".image" resource in the exe.

My question is how can I modify some minor things of this program starting from this resource?

Comment: You could if you had the sources. Do you?

Comment: I've only got this exe. By looking inside the ".image" resource I can see string constants, method names and so on so I think that the source is not strictly necessary. One of the problems I'm encountering is that there is a lot of gibberish and I don't understand how values are encoded and methods called. It is my understanding that VSE has a runtime (vm) to wich this ".image" (i think it is a smalltalk image fiel embedded) is feeded for execution, more or less like .Net.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The .image section of the exe file contains a "Smalltalk image". This is not something you alter directly, it is generated by the Smalltalk Development Environment. The image contains both code (in IL form) and "live objects persisted to disk".

The exe file is "just a loader", it starts the VM, loads the image into memory, and starts the application.